# Use ts without losing exit value

Tags: shell-script

I have a build script that executes a long command that produces lots of output which went like this:

```
./compile
```

In order to troubleshoot compilation performance, I want to use `ts` (from [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)) which prefixes each output line with a timestamp.  So I updated my script like this:

```
bash -c "./compile | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'"
```

This works, but now the exit value is always `0`, event when `compile` fails (I think, because `ts` exits without an error).

How can I update my script to return `compile`'s exit code while using `ts`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you’re using Bash, you can use its `$PIPESTATUS` which is an array containing the different exit codes from the commands in a pipeline:

```
bash -c './compile | ts "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"; exit "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"'
```

`zsh` has a similar feature but uses the `$pipestatus` array instead (also remember `zsh` arrays are numbered from `1`, not `0`).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `pipefail` option which is supported by a few shells including `bash`, `ksh93`, `zsh`, `mksh`, `yash` and busybox `ash` (and [will be added to the specification of `sh` in the next major version of POSIX](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=789#c4103)) and causes the exit status of a pipeline to be that of the right-most failing command.

For instance, the exit status of `(exit 3) | (exit 4) | (exit 0)` would be `4`.

```
bash -o pipefail -c "./compile | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'"
```

Would return with the exit status of `./compile` unless `ts` itself fails.